# MorphMany laravel relation does not work for some reason

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.6 version, here is my Test model file

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\data\Models;

use Illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $table = 'tests';

    /*
    * Test - TestTranslation relation
    * Test has many translations
    */      
    public function translations() 
    { 

        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Data\Models\TestTranslation'); 

    }       

    /*
    * Test - Image relation
    * Test can have an thumbnail
    */  
    public function thumbnails() 
    { 

        return $this->morphMany('App\Model\Data\Models\Image', 'type'); 

    }

}
```

Here is my Image model

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Data\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $table = 'images';

    /*
    * Image belongs to Post, Account, Comment
    */      
    public function type()
    {

        return $this->morphTo();

    }   

}
```

Here is my Database scheme for Images table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->enum('type', ['avatar', 'thumbnail', 'generic'])->default('generic');
            $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->enum('type_type',[
                "Account",
                "Comment",
                "Post",
                "Skill",
                "Test"
            ])->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('images');
    }
}
```

In AppServiceProvider I linked 'Test' to my model file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use App\Model\Data\Models\Account;
use App\Model\Data\Models\EmailChangeConfirmation;
use App\Model\Observers\Common\AccountObserver;
use App\Model\Observers\Common\EmailChangeConfirmationObserver;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        Relation::morphMap([
            'Account' => 'App\Model\Data\Models\Account',
            'Comment' => 'App\Model\Data\Models\Comment',
            'Post' => 'App\Model\Data\Models\Post',
            'Skill' => 'App\Model\Data\Models\Skill',
            'Test' => 'App\Model\Data\Models\Test'
        ]);     

        if(env('APP_ENV') != 'testing') {
            Account::observe(AccountObserver::class);
            EmailChangeConfirmation::observe(EmailChangeConfirmationObserver::class);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment('local', 'testing')) {
            $this->app->register(DuskServiceProvider::class);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have more morhpMany types, and all of them works fine. But for some reason, this Test relation that I added recently always returns an empty collection, even tough I am sure that test has thumbnails. Cause:
[image]
in this screenshot, I have records in database that each test has two images. Their ID matches ids of created tests and type is "Test". I tried to clear all caches, run composer dump-autoload but none of them helped.

Maybe someone can help identify what is wrong here? Because as I said before other types as Post, Account works fine.

Comment: Please submit test records data from your database.

Comment: Please add your query code.

Comment: please adjust your import `use Illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model;` to `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` might this will resolve the problem.

and the `namespace` aswell